# enumeration values in json

Tags: python, json, cgi

Do a simple screening values. but do not understand why only takes a few values, not the entire list.
I use CGI written in python. displays 136 values, but in the file more than 1000 values.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import cgi
import cgitb
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
cityRu = form.getvalue('city')
print ("Content-type: text/html")
print ("")
cities = json.loads(open('json/cities.json').read())
ourResult = cities
for rs in ourResult:
    print (rs['name_translations']['en']+' - '+rs['name_translations']['ru'])
```

Comment: Without seeing your data we can only guess...

Comment: give you a link to json?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kw4tuiuhdatg01a/cities.json?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is one of the `dict` objects doesn't have the key `'ru'`, so use this if you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import cgi
import cgitb
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
cityRu = form.getvalue('city')
print ("Content-type: text/html")
print ("")
cities = json.loads(open('json/cities.json').read())
ourResult = cities
for rs in ourResult:
    try:
        print (rs['name_translations']['en']+' - '+rs['name_translations']['ru'])
    except KeyError:
        print ("ERROR WITH KEYS")
        # do something else...
```

You can also do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import cgi
import cgitb
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
cityRu = form.getvalue('city')
print ("Content-type: text/html")
print ("")
with open('json/cities.json') as jf:
    cities = json.load(jf)
cities_with_ru = filter(lambda x: 'ru' in x['name_translations'], cities)
for rs in cities_with_ru:
    print (rs['name_translations']['en']+' - '+rs['name_translations']['ru'])
```

This could be nicer, but I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Seems like `'en'` exists for all items in the list, but you should verify.

Comment: Well, of course!
I just started learning python and did not think that because of this script may stop. thought that displays an empty string if there is no value. thank you very much!works!